# Block-level deduplicating filesystem 3

Tags: backup

I've got the "problem" - how to backup KVM virtuals on compressed/deduplicated filesystem. It looks that NO enterprise stable filesystem exists yet ( free of charge ). But I found,I hope, "QUADSTOR" solution - quadstor.com Have U any experiences with it ??? Pa.

Comment: ZFS offers block level deduplication.  Not sure what you think qualifies as "enterprise stable" though (in my world, 'enterprise' usually means overpriced and underpowered, but maybe I'm just old and cynical :)

Comment: It should probably be mentioned though that compression and deduplication impacts **heavily** on performance, especially on very large filesystems.    If you just want a backup store then this is perhaps not an issue, but for any kind of live-access storage with a filesystem of any appreciable size it can be a killer

Answer (score 0):

because I'm technical guy, the 'enterprise" system mean stable, robust, quick, but from business view, U're right :-).

So targered backup FS is about 30TB space on dedicated server